# sed replacing a string with warning when string not found

Tags: sed, counting

I want to change a line in a bunch of similar scripts using sed. Some of these scripts do not actually contain the line I want to change. However, sed doesn't tell me it didn't change the line cause it wasn't there. Any ideas on how I can make sed spit out a warning?
Say, I have script one

```
    log export ALBET=0.155
    log export ALBEG=0.218
    log export RADGHGCOEF=1.0
```

and script two

```
    log export ALBET=0.168
    log export ALBEG=0.201
```

then

```
    sed -i 's/RADGHGCOEF=.*/RADGHGCOEF=2.0/' script
```

works on both on them, but I'd like to be informed that there was actually no line containing RADGHGCOEF to be changed in script 2.
Thanks!

Comment: may be use `grep` before `sed`? something like `grep -q 'RADGHGCOEF' script && sed '...' || echo 'not found'`

Answer (score 5):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -i -pe '$found++ if s/RADGHGCOEF=.*/RADGHGCOEF=2.0/; END { warn "$ARGV: not found\n" if !$found; }' script
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-i` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file).

`$ARGV` : current input file name.

`$found++ if s/.../.../`: increment by 1 the `$found` variable from its `undef` initial value, so that it now becomes 1 (or more, depending on how many times the substitution occurred).
`END { ... }` : execute the code after reading the entire input file.
`if !$found` : if the substitution never occurred, `$found` is `false` in boolean context), otherwise `true`.

**SEE ALSO:**

[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlvar`: Perl predefined variables](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can use this `awk` solution instead of `sed`:

```
awk '{n += sub(/RADGHGCOEF=.*/, "RADGHGCOEF=2.0")} 1; END{exit !n}' file &&
echo 'search string found!' || echo 'search string not found!'
```

This command will exit with `1` is substitutions occurred otherwise it wil exit with `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Testing with `grep` before the `sed` (like @Sundeep suggested in a comment) is better than manipulating weird options of `sed`. This solution is just for fun:

You can let `sed` write something to stderr when it finds a string:

```
sed 's/RADGHGCOEF=.*/RADGHGCOEF=2.0/; /RADGHGCOEF/e echo yes >&2' script
```

I like to have it on stderr, avoiding it being written into the file when you add `-i`.
When you want to `test` the output, you want to convert stderr back to stdout.
Putting things together:

```
 test -z "$(sed -i 's/RADGHGCOEF=.*/RADGHGCOEF=2.0/;
                     /RADGHGCOEF/e echo yes >&2' script 2>&1)" && echo "Nothing found"
```

Answer (score 0):

Code snippet to make desired replacement, default output to screen (final message printed to `STDERR`).

Run script with option `-i` for in-place replacement - `perl -i script.pl file_name`

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $count;

while( <> ) {
    chomp;
    $count ++ if s/RADGHGCOEF=.*/RADGHGCOEF=2.0/;
    say;
}

if( $count ) {
    say STDERR "Info: replaced $count time(s)";
} else {
    say STDERR "Info: nothing to replace";
}
```

Input file `some_data`

```
log export ALBET=0.155
log export ALBEG=0.218
log export RADGHGCOEF=1.0
```

Run as `./script.pl some_data`

```
log export ALBET=0.155
log export ALBEG=0.218
log export RADGHGCOEF=2.0
Info: replaced 1 time(s)
```

Run as `perl -i script.pl some_data`

```
Info: replaced 1 time(s)
```